# Check if values in one vector are less than values in another vector (of different length) and populate a table with Y/N answers

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Thanks in advance for your help!

**The Goal:** I'm looking at housing affordability data, building a tool showing housing affordability by occupation. I have a data frame of occupations and their median wages and a data frame of all of the home values for all properties in the area.

**The Challenge:** I'm looking for a way to compare each of the home values to an affordability metric specific to each occupation, and populate a data frame with TRUE/FALSE, Y/N or 1/0 if the home value is below the metric. The end result would be data frame with home values as observations and one column for each occupation.

Here's some sample code to illustrate the question better:

I'm trying to combine this:

```
Job          Median Wage  Can Afford
Lawyer       104756       272365.5
Bus Driver   26598        69154.8
Retail Sales 48923        127199.8
```

And this:

```
Property Value
927346
12345
87492
12734
73642
```

To create something like this:

```
Value   Lawyer   Bus Driver   Retail Sales
927346  N        N            N
12345   Y        N            Y
87492   Y        N            Y
12734   Y        Y            Y
73642   Y        Y            Y
```

Running Rstudio 3.5. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check your expected.  It doesn't look right (based on the example)

Comment: @akrun sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Comment: Why is Retail Sales all Y from 2to 5 by looking at the value of Retail Sales in the first data\

Comment: @akrun, oh makes sense now! the affordability metric is 2.6 *wage, I should have included that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` from `purrr` to do this.  Loop through the rows of individual elements of 'Job' , 'MedianWage', check whether the 'PropertyValue' in second dataset is less than 2.6 times the 'MedianWage' to create a logical column and bind the `list` of datasets to single one while combining with the first column of 'df2'

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(df1$Job, df1$MedianWage, ~ 
                           df2 %>% 
                            transmute(!! .x :=  PropertyValue < 2.6 * .y)) %>% 
     bind_cols(df2, .)
```

Or with `pmap`

```
pmap(df1, ~
       df2 %>% 
         transmute(!! ..1 := PropertyValue < 2.6 * ..2)) %>% 
  bind_cols(df2, .)
#   PropertyValue Lawyer Bus Driver Retail Sales
#1        927346  FALSE      FALSE        FALSE
#2         12345   TRUE       TRUE         TRUE
#3         87492   TRUE      FALSE         TRUE
#4         12734   TRUE       TRUE         TRUE
#5         73642   TRUE      FALSE         TRUE
```

Changing it to "Y/N" can be done either using `ifelse` or by converting logical vector to numeric index

```
pmap(df1, ~
         df2 %>% 
            transmute(!! ..1 := c("N", "Y")[1 + (PropertyValue < 2.6 * ..2)])) %>%
    bind_cols(df2, .)
```

---

Or use `sapply` from `base R`

```
cbind(df2, sapply(setNames(2.6 * df1$MedianWage, df1[[1]]), `>`, df2$PropertyValue))
```

NOTE: It is better to have a logical column (`TRUE/FALSE`) instead of `Y/N`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Job = c("Lawyer", "Bus Driver", "Retail Sales"
), MedianWage = c(104756L, 26598L, 48923L)), .Names = c("Job", 
"MedianWage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(PropertyValue = c(927346L, 12345L, 87492L, 12734L, 
73642L)), .Names = "PropertyValue", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Oh my gosh, thank you so much for your help! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

`Map` the values and fill them in against the matching names:

```
df2[df1$Job] <- Map(function(mw,pv) pv < (2.6*mw), df1[["MedianWage"]], df2["PropertyValue"])

#  PropertyValue Lawyer Bus Driver Retail Sales
#1        927346  FALSE      FALSE        FALSE
#2         12345   TRUE       TRUE         TRUE
#3         87492   TRUE      FALSE         TRUE
#4         12734   TRUE       TRUE         TRUE
#5         73642   TRUE      FALSE         TRUE
```

Comment: Or without anonymous call `Map('>=', 2.6 * df1[["MedianWage"]], df2["PropertyValue"])`